# jQuery UI Draggable/Sortable find element(s) you're dragging over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do you find the elements your dragging over with jQuery UI. I've searched various event props from the 'over' or 'sort' events but non of them seem to contain that information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ondragover:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event-onMethod/onDragOverExample.htm

Sounds like should do what you need, but I dont know of any jQuery way of getting this info.

It isnt a DOM event but it is stated here that it will work on *most* browsers:
http://help.dottoro.com/ljrkqflw.php